# Блокируется взаимодействие через iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

При входе на любой сайт вставляется iframe.

При взаимодействии (клики по кнопкам, ссылкам) с iframe некоторые сайты выдают такую ошибку:

"Этот контент заблокирован. Чтобы устранить неполадку, свяжитесь с владельцем сайта."

Выдают не все сайты, лишь некоторые. Кто-то сталкивался? Как такое решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: взял код [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), все отлично работает. вы что-то не то написали, приведите свой код. мой код: <iframe src="https://wikipedia.org" width="1000" height="600"></iframe>